# Optimized longest_run func

Tags: python-3.x

guys. I implemented the function (my homework) that does the following:
  Assumes L is a list of integers containing at least 2 elements.
    Finds the longest run of numbers in L, where the longest run can
    either be monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing. 
    In case of a tie for the longest run, choose the longest run 
    that occurs first.
    Does not modify the list.
    Returns the sum of the longest run

```
def run_for_el(L, n, operand):
    entry = [L[n]]
    count = n
    while eval ("L[count]" + operand + "L[count+1]"):
        entry.append(L[count+1])
        if count < len(L)-2:
            count += 1
        else: break
    return entry

def longest_run2(L):
    if len(L) == 2:
        return sum(L)
    storage = []
    for n in range(len(L) - 2):

        if L[n] <=  L[n+1]:
            operand = "<="
            storage.append(run_for_el(L, n, operand))

        if L[n] >= L[n+1]:
            operand = ">="
            storage.append(run_for_el(L, n, operand))

    maximum = storage [0]
    for entry in storage:
        if len (entry) > len (maximum):
            maximum = entry
    return (sum (maximum))
```

It is a right decision and passed all the test cases. The point is I'm not sure it's the most efficient method. Who of guru's can suggest a better one?  I'd like to optimize it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the advantage of reusing function in terms of performance. I just wrote simply like this.

```
def longest_run(l):
    # increasing
    max_len_inc = cur_len = 1
    cur_sum = l[0]
    for n in range(1, len(l)):
        if l[n] >= l[n-1]:
            cur_sum += l[n]
            cur_len += 1
        else:
            if cur_len > max_len_inc:
                max_len_inc = cur_len
                max_sum_inc = cur_sum
                min_idx_inc = n
            cur_len = 1
            cur_sum = l[n]
        if cur_len > max_len_inc:
            max_len_inc = cur_len
            max_sum_inc = cur_sum
            min_idx_inc = n

    # decreasing
    max_len_dec = cur_len = 1
    cur_sum = l[0]
    for n in range(1, len(l)):
        if l[n] <= l[n-1]:
            cur_sum += l[n]
            cur_len += 1
        else:
            if cur_len > max_len_dec:
                max_len_dec = cur_len
                max_len_dec = cur_sum
                min_idx_dec = n
            cur_len = 1
            cur_sum = l[n]
    if cur_len > max_len_dec:
        max_len_dec = cur_len
        max_sum_dec = cur_sum
        min_idx_dec = n

    if max_len_inc > max_len_dec:
        return(max_sum_inc)
    elif max_len_inc < max_len_dec:
        return(max_sum_dec)
    else:
        if min_idx_inc < min_idx_dec:
            return (max_sum_inc)
        else:
            return (max_sum_dec)
```

As you can see, only `l[n] >= l[n-1]` part is different, so it looks verbose and redundant, I know. But what about the speed?

```
l = [9, 1,2,3, 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4, 9, 8,7,6,5,4, 1,2,34,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,14,16,19]

import time

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(500):
    a = longest_run(l)
print(time.time() - start_time)  # 0.011501550674438477

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(500):
    a = longest_run2(l)
print(time.time() - start_time)  # 2.1403748989105225
```

Simple solution is 200x times faster. Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Yes, that's helpful. Actually, my main goal is to know approaches of other more  experienced guys, each answer is valuable. Perhaps there exist more practical methods. And  a  question, in case of a tie how will your func choose the longest run that occurs first?

Comment: Oops you're right... I should add `min_idx` or something to keep the smaller index. Will do that later. And I myself too want to know other methods than simply iterating array by indexes.

Comment: I do hope other guys can share their experience with us)

Comment: Tie length condition added. Time difference is not changed.